# websites navbar causing issues

Tags: html, css, web

I am just creating simple HTML website for class. I am having issues with the navbar pushing things apart. I am unsure how to fix as I have went over this for hours.

You see how the navbar is pushing the content over .I am writing this from scatch and thought everything was fine until i started adding content and noticed

http://hydra.sullivan.edu/mmoore/Assn01/index.php

Comment: Also why is the line not going to the end of the footer ? Thanks Matt k.

Comment: your #content height isn't set, so it will only go as far down as the content inside it. not sure about the push-over part though...

Comment: You have to put the #nav in the #content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
#nav {
  float:left;
  padding-top:1em;
  position:relative;
  right:140px;
}
```

The #nav element is actually taking up that space, but you've just shifted it to the left. So the other elements will still wrap around where it used to be.

Comment: Yes i understand that is where problem is originally but i am unable to figure out how to fix it or what css should be .

Comment: set the width of #nav, then set the width of #content, remove the 228px margin-left from #content, then float both left.